# Can't set programmatically logger level for root appender

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j

In my java project I use log4j. If I want programmatically set logger for root apender I use this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    AppenderSkeleton consoleAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("Console");
    AppenderSkeleton fileAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("File");
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But now I update to `log4j2 (slf4j)`

And now here my code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

AppenderSkeleton consoleAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("Console");

AppenderSkeleton fileAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("File");
```

But now I get error:

```
error: cannot find symbol Logger.getRootLogger()
```

How I can set programmatically root level for `slf4j` ?

Answer (score 2):

slf4j is just a unified interface to emit log messages. It is implemented by different logging backends such as [log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). However, slf4j does not extend to the logging configuration, which is highly backend specific. Therefore, it does not provide methods to change the log system configuration. This still needs to be done using the backend specific classes. In your case of log4j, you also cannot cast the `org.slf4j.Logger` to a `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`, as the latter does not extend the `org.slf4j.Logger`. You have to keep your old code for that task and adjust it to the new log4j2 programmatic convention. See [the log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) for details.

Comment: _"You have to keep your old code for that task."_ ... Actually the OP needs to update the old log4j 1.2 programmatic configuration to new log4j2 programmatic configuration. Otherwise you nailed it.

Comment: @Karsten SchnitterIf I use "org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("File")" the result is null because I use "log4j2.xml" (not log4j.xml as before")

Comment: I incorporated the feedback of @PetrJaneček in the answer. You need to use the log4j2 conventions now.